# Can you flash any android device with "fastbood flash" command (of the adb)?

Tags: rom-flashing

If an android device is rooted, and you have an image for it. Can you flash it with the "fastboot flash" command of the adb?
If not, why?
If yes, then what are all the "odin" tools for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Certain manufacturers decide for whatever reason that they don't want to ship their products with support for 'fastboot'. It's really down to what the device manufacturer decides to do. To find out why, you'd have to find an engineer from the company in question and ask them why they decided to write their own protocol instead of using fastboot.

Most devices *are* fastboot compatible, while other manufacturers implement their own, proprietary interfaces. The primary example of this in today's world is Samsung, which uses their own, custom protocol to communicate with their devices - which requires a tool like Odin or [Heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/) to work.

Comment: What about custom recoveries? Can those be flashed to any device with fastboot???

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can't use fastboot to flash a custom recovery to a device - you need to use Odin/Heimdall for Samsung, etc. Nor can you flash any recovery to a device using fastboot - to use a recovery on a device it must be purpose-built for the device (e.g. You can only flash Nexus 5 recoveries on a Nexus 5, trying to install a Nexus 5 recovery on a Nexus 6 might brick your Nexus 6)